# Accessing a ManyToManyField's contents for a Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm making a low-spec e-bay clone, I'm trying to implement a watchlist function but the problem is I can't access the ManyToManyField in the Watchlist model so I can use the contents of the field in the template I'm using. To display each user's watchlist to them, so far I only get this result:
[image] but I need to get a result like so:
[image]

Code I'm using:

**watchlist.html**

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block title %} {{name}}'s Watchlist {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h2>{{name}}'s Watchlist</h2>

{% for listing in watchlist %}
<div class='listing'>
    <h3>{{ listing.list_title}}</h3>
    {% if listing.img_url == "" %}
        <a href='#'><img src="{% static 'auctions/img404.png' %}" class='img-fluid'></a>
    {% else %}
        <a href='#'><img src="{{ listing.img_url }}" class="img-fluid" alt='image of {{ listing.list_title }}'></a>
    {% endif %}
    <p>
        {{ listing.desc }}
    </p>
    <p>
        Current Bid: ${{ listing.start_bid }}
    </p>
    {% if listing.category == "" %}
        <p>Category: No Category Listed</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Category: {{ listing.category }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary' id='go'>Go To Listing</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def render_listing(request, title):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BidForm(request.POST)
        bid = int(request.POST['new_bid'])
        listing = Auction_Listing.objects.get(list_title=title)
        comments = Auction_Comments.objects.all().filter(auction_id=listing)
        if bid < listing.start_bid:
            error = True
        else:
            error = False
            listing.start_bid = bid
            listing.save()
        return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html', {
            "listing": listing,
            "form": form,
            "comments": comments,
            "error": error
        })
    else:
        form = BidForm()
        listing = Auction_Listing.objects.get(list_title=title)
        comments = Auction_Comments.objects.all().filter(auction_id=listing)
        return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html', {
            "listing": listing,
            "form": form,
            "comments": comments,
            "error": False
        })

@login_required
def watchlist_render(request):
    user = request.user.id
    username = request.user.username
    watched = Watchlist.objects.filter(user_id=user)
    return render(request, 'auctions/watchlist.html', {
        "watchlist": watched,
        "name": username
    })
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE

CATEGORIES = [
        ('Appliances', 'Appliances'),
         ('Tech', 'Tech'), 
         ('Gaming', 'Gaming'), 
         ('Fashion', 'Fashion'), 
         ('Sports and Fitness','Sports and Fitness'), 
         ('Other','Other'),
         ("Hygiene and Medicine","Hygiene and Medicine"), 
         ("Stationery","Stationery"),
        ('Decor', 'Decor'), 
        ('Furniture','Furniture'), 
        ('Cars and Mechanical Things','Cars and Mechanical Things'), 
        ("Tools","Tools")
    ]

# Create models here
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Auction_Listing(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    list_title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=324)
    img_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    start_bid = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES, max_length=35, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID:{self.id}, {self.list_title}: {self.desc}, {self.start_bid} posted by user:{self.user_id} in Category:{self.category}, url:{self.img_url}"

class Bids(models.Model):
    bid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    auction_id = models.ManyToManyField(Auction_Listing)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID:{self.id}, Bid {self.bid} posted by user:{self.user_id} on auction {self.auction_id}"

class Auction_Comments(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=324, default='N/A')
    auction_id = models.ManyToManyField(Auction_Listing)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID:{self.id}, Comment: {self.comment} posted by user:{self.user_id} on auction {self.auction_id}"

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE,default=1)
    auction_id = models.ManyToManyField(Auction_Listing, related_name='auction_listing')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID:{self.user_id} on auction {self.auction_id}"
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Kind Regards

PrimeBeat

EDIT: The results of the links as  @nigel222 requested
[image]

Comment: Use your browser's "view page source" to see what `<a href='#'><img src="{{ listing.img_url }}" ...` has turned into. Post that here if you are still stuck.

Comment: I added the result to the post @nigel222

Comment: So the test `{% if listing.img_url == "" %}` isn't working right and the url field is some other flavour of empty? None not "", probably. Inspect it. Or take a stab at it with a "Falsy" test `{% if not listing.img_url %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh CS50W. I love this course. Anyway, I recognize where you've gotten stuck. What you're doing is that you're passing the Watchlist object in the context, instead of passing a list of listings.

This is why your `{% for listing in watchlist %}` is failing, because `watchlist` is a single object.

What you can do instead is, in your views.py, get the full list of watched items, and pass in that list in as the context. So:

```
@login_required
def watchlist_render(request):
    user = request.user.id
    username = request.user.username

    # This will give you the Watchlist instance
    watchlist = Watchlist.objects.filter(user_id=user)


    # I would recommend renaming auction_id (in your models.py file) to `auctionItems` or 'listings'
    # because it returns an object of type Auction_Listing, rather than just the id.
    # for eg. watchlist.listings.all() allows you to instinctively understand what you're trying to do.
    # Now you can extract the listings from the watchlist
    listings = watchlist.auction_id.all()
    return render(request, 'auctions/watchlist.html', {
        "watchlist": listings,
        "name": username
    })
```

Now in your template you can access each listing in the list: `{% for listing in listings %}`

Comment: So I legit just copied the code and pasted it, ran the server, and once again an error... ```'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'auctions'``` (I renamed auction_id to auctions in the model, migrated and everything, I also changed the code accordingly)

Comment: I'm guessing that's happening because your QuerySet is empty. Do one thing, print both the watchlist variable and the listings variable to the console. If the watchlist is empty then listings won't be able to access anything and will throw this error.